Relationship between Dot Product and the Sum of a Vector or Number of Entries
This is a computer science question with a mathematical basis so I thought I'd ask it here. I recently asked an algorithms question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79047040/complexity-analysis-for-computing-the-square-of-a-graph
The main idea is to propose and analyze an algorithm that computed G^2 from the graph G where G^@ has the same nodes but has edges between nodes if there are at most 2 edges between these nodes in the original graph. Both graphs are directed.
My algorithm was a simple brute force method, iterate through each node and iterate through all neighbours and iterate through all of the neighbours' neighbours.
The in-degree and out-degree of a node are just the number of edges going into a node and out of a node respectively. I realized that the number of operations is simply the sum over of the (in-degree + 1) * out-degree across all nodes as each node's neighbours (out-degree) are processed once when processing that node (say n) itself and in-degree times when processing that n's neighbours when n is being considered the neighbour of another node (there will be in-degree such nodes for which n is considered an immediate neighbour).
This is just the dot product of the in-degree and out-degree vectors. There are some useful properties. The number of entries in each vector is equal to V the number of nodes and the the sum of all entries in the in-degree vector = the sum of all entries in the out-degree vector = the total number of edges E. I would like to know if the value of the dot product of these vectors can be quantified linearly in terms of V, E or some linear combination of them or whether or not it must be some non-linear polynomial.

Call this doct product $V_2$. From what you said, $V_2$ is the cardinality of the set of all paths of length $2$ in the graph. In general, $V_2$ will not depend only on $V$ and $E$. You can definitely construct two graphs with same nodes and same number of edges with different $V_2$. If you want an upper bound for $V_2$, I guess you cannot do better than $V(V-1)^2$ or $E^{3/2}$ by looking at the complete graph. And $E^{3/2}$ is surely not an upper bound, because you can get to $E^2/4$ by looking at a graph with V odd and $E=V-1$ edges that all go through a fixed vertex. So no, there cannot be a linear upper bound in $V$ and $E$. A bilinear one exists which is $E(V-1)$, but I guess this is not what you meant.
